# Searching for a better solution than folded if statements for undefined properties of an object

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement, undefined

This is a very basic issue about if statements. It doesn’t necessarily effect only javascript.

If `object.user` is `undefined` this will break:

```
if ( object.user.name ) {
  sayMyName();
} else {
  object.user = {};
  object.user.name = 'Jane Doe';
  sayMyName();
}
```

because it can not read a property of undefined. So i put the else stuff in a function and folded the if into another if:

```
function anonymous(object) {
  object.user = {};
  object.user.name = 'Jane Doe';
  sayMyName();
}

if ( object.user ) {
  if ( object.user.name ) {
    sayMyName();
  } else {
    anonymous();
  }
} else {
  anonymous();
}
```

But this looks like bad code to me. This case must be a common problem. Or at least i have it quite often. Is there any good solution for this?

EDIT:

@Mritunjay's proposal

```
if(object && object.user && object.user.name){...}
```

is way better, but it doesn’t seem to be the best solution. Imagine a if-statements that tries to get `obj.some.very.very.deep.property`. I‘m currently trying to write a helper-function like `checkPropertySafely(object.user.name);` that goes back to `object`, and checks every property recursively, no matter how deep it is. So basically i try to automate @Mritunjay’s manually written statement.

Comment: `obj.some.very.very.deep.property` should not happen. A function should work with what it needs. If it needs `deep`, then give it `deep`, not `obj`. See [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use bellow in this situation

```
if(object.user && object.user.name){...}
```

BTW you should check if `object` also exists.

```
if(object && object.user && object.user.name){...}
```

Comment: shame on me! i thought that wouldn‘t work. maybe because i didn‘t heed the order. but i wonder if there is an even shorter way do do this.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to write the helper-function. Here it is:

```
function propertyExists(property) {
    var statement = '';
    var prevItem = '';

    property.split(".").forEach(function(item, index) {
        if (index != 0) {statement += ' && '}
        statement += prevItem+item;
        prevItem += item+'.';
    });

    return eval(statement);
}
```

With this function, i can now simply do this:

```
if ( propertyExists('object.user.name') ) {
  sayMyName();
} else {
  anonymous();
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is very useful until I am checking to many levels like `a.b.c.d.e.f......`, and in this situation it seems a bad design.